# show livewallpaper in android

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

How to show livewallpaper for your app in android. I have created WallpaperService class and put my all logical drawing stuff in a class which extends Engine. All this will work for your system. I want this particular service to run only for my app in background. Any one have idea?

Comment: use this for live wallpaper http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-livewallpaer-tutorial.html

Comment: Naveen:-I tried this app but i want live wallpaper only for my app and not for system. :)

Comment: have u creat live wallpaper or not like this

Comment: yeah i have created like this only.. but this will set to your system.. i want if i open my app, Then that wallpaper should run in background and whenever i close my app that live wallpaper shouldnt visible.

Comment: if u want to that type of work in app so that is not livewallpaper that image change on runtime from anywhere like (gallery ) so refused that and use one activity and setbackrounf and chenge beckground at runtime like pic image from gallery and set in layout on runtime

Comment: Naveen- So, For my scenario, I cant use Wallpaper service and Engine stuffs.

Comment: just u think its a part or your application not a wallpaper live wallpaper run only home screen in android not any more

Comment: Yes.. you are absolutly correct. Thnx Bro!!

Comment: Can i write my own activity and extend to Wallpaper service?

Comment: wallpaper service is the part of wallpaper and activity is the part of android ui screen

Comment: Yes.. Can we Extend Wallpaper Service by writing our own Service.